# error in grid search optimization -ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.optimizers.Adam object at 0x0000027A2BE4BAC8>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

i tried to optimize my DL model using the grid search algorithm
it runs and when it complete it arise the following error - note that i used both tensorflow and keras - cause i didn't understand the reason of the error.
i try to import just each of them , but i doesnt work also

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer
 import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
 from keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from numpy import argmax
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout
#Grid  search optimization 
def create_model(learn_rate, dropout_rate):
    # Create model
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(260, input_dim=265, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(240, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Dense(56, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add( layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='class'))
    # Compile the model
    adam = Adam(lr=learn_rate)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model



# Create the model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)


learn_rate = [0.001, 0.02, 0.2]
dropout_rate = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4]
batch_size = [10, 20, 30]
epochs = [1, 5, 10]

seed = 42

# Make a dictionary of the grid search parameters
param_grid = dict(learn_rate=learn_rate, dropout_rate=dropout_rate, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs )

# Build and fit the GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,
                    cv=KFold(random_state=seed), verbose=10)

grid_results = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

when i run grid.fit

it runs then show the following error

```
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.optimizers.Adam object at 0x0000027A2BE4BAC8>
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please include imports in your question, it sounds like a mix between keras and tf.keras which is not supported

Comment: updated according to your comment

Comment: You are mixing keras and tf.kerad imports, do not do that

Comment: i try to import each of them only.. but it aslo did not work.. should i import which one?

Comment: It does not matter which one you choose, the point is not to mix them in the imports. It is up to you if you want to use tf.keras or keras